# Call API/Resolve page before Refresh in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router, angular-resolver

when I refresh page(f5) for a moment footer is just coming to top, then page is loaded.
I am using resolver for load data from api. When I route from another component everything works as expected, data is loaded before. How to load data from API before refresh, then load component? Like resolver?

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private dataService: DataService, private router: Router
              , private modalService: NgbModal) {
            this.completeServer = this.route.snapshot.data['completeServer'];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    handleData();
  }
```

On screenshot I catched a moment, when page look like I described it above.

[image]

Comment: Not exactly a useful thing, rather you should only show the footer when the data from the api has been loaded

Comment: I am trying to make sure that I follow you correctly.  All you need is for the component to load when the data is received?

Comment: @Winnemucca Data is loading, but after pressing f5 (refreshing website)
for a moment, the website look like this. On screenshot I just catched this moment, when website is trimmed.
I am looking for solution to this.
So I mean, loading component when data is received, should solve the problem.
And that's how I solved it when routing between components on website. With resolver. But don't know how to implement this on refreshing

Comment: I believe handleData() could be called  in a parent component.  You could pass that data to a child component through an ()Input.  With the input you can add an *ngIf statement.  It is hard to give an exact answer.  I realize you have a resolver, but I can only see so much of your architecture.

Comment: @Winnemucca Handle data is just formating data received from resolver, and drawing chart.

Comment: Currently I am just hiding footer on page load.